# How can I get the source of a HTTP request?

Tags: http, request, owasp, http-referer

The referer header does not always provide the full url of the site spawning the http request, and I would like to know if there is any way I could figure out the source url of the site that is making the request.

I am currently using OWASP ZAP as a proxy, but am unable to trace some of the http requests back to the source site due to the incomplete referer.

Comment: Nothing like this is included by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the full URL in the ZAP Search tab. If that doesnt work try searching for just the path.
If the URL is generated by JavaScript then that might not work.
Depending on how you are exploring the app you may be able to work back through the history and work it out by a process of elimination, but that could take a while...